# Angular 2 router without route changes / history

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I like the benefits of the Angular 2 Router like Guards, Resolver, using navigateTo etc.

But in my app i dont want to change the route at all. So it should always stay "/" without changes in browser history. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but in this case, you can't use `routerLink` in your templates.

You can use instead user interaction within your app to trigger events `(click)="announce(this)"` or `(keyup)="execute(that)"`

Put in your routing configuration :

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' } //redirect all path to your home page
```

Some remarks about that:

- Users can't access deep links (i.e: yourapp.com/awesome-article-1)
- You'll have some seo issues with search engines bots...

Comment: But i do have important routes with guards etc. I just dont want them to show up in browser bar.